# After update OS X 10.9.3 MacBook Pro 2010, Restart suddenly

Tags: macos, restart

Yesterday I get OS X 10.9.3 after update, my MBP 2010 getting restart when I open VLC, Illustrator and sometimes Safari. The message shows "Your Computer restarted because of a Problem. Press any key to continue starting up".

**Why this happen?**

Answer (score 1):

There are reports of Dropbox causing kernel panics on 10.9.3. If you have Dropbox installed, try quitting the dropbox agent. If the kernel panics cease, then wait for Dropbox to update their software.

First, click the dropbox icon in the menu bar, then click the gear icon in the bottom-right.
[image: Dropbox menu]

Then quit Dropbox from the popup menu.
[image]

Comment: Is there any solutions for this? Chrome also have this issue? coz when i open chrome that time also getting restart. other MAC apps are working fine.eg:webstrome, safari..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a kernel problem. It could be that you have a corrupt hard drive and that the installation was garbled during the install. It could be that you had a corrupted version of the installer (though it likely wouldn't have finished installing were that the case). You should run disk utility to verify your drive isn't damaged, then reinstall the OS.

Comment: there are any way to check update successfully installed or not??

Comment: I'm not sure. One thing you can do is run Disk Utility and run Verify Disk on your HD. If that goes well, try Repair Permissions.